# How do I remove a specific span inside a Table in HTML using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a coded snippet from the elements tab of the browser, how do I remove the selected span? please help, I just want to delete the span under the fourth 'td' under the tr that has the class 'danger'.

```
<table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped"><thead>
          </thead><tbody>
            <tr id="31" class="danger">
            <td>

                 </td>
                 <td class="tabledit-view-mode">

                 </td> 
                 <td class="tabledit-view-mode">

                 <td class="tabledit-view-mode">
                      <span class="tabledit-span" style="display: 
                      inline;">123</span>
                      <input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm fas 
                         fa-eye-slash" type="password" name="PASSWORD" 
                         value="" style="display: none;" id="password0" 
                         disabled="">
                 </td>
                 <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;"> 

                </td>                  
          </td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the following jQuery

```
$('#editable_table > tbody > tr:([class*=danger]) > td[3] > span').remove()
```

but got an error of

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #editable_table > tbody > tr:([class*=danger]) > td[3] > span
at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
at n (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.onAlways (UserManagement.php:120)
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.tabledit.min.js:6)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
```

is there any other way for javascript or even jquery?

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: hello, I tried using this line of code
$('#editable_table > tbody > tr:([class*=danger]) > td[3] > span').remove(). but I keep on getting an error :(

Comment: OK. then quicky add that to question as well as actual html sample instead of image or this question will be quickly downvoted. Also take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I apologize, because I thought it would be too long of a code if I got this part of the code from the 'Inspect Element' part of my browser.

Comment: Add the relevant code, i.e your HTML structure, and the code that you already tried, together with the error message you receive while trying that code.

Comment: That's ok. Just don't take the votes personally and keep editing. You don't need all the code....just the minimal to represent the issue. But questions need to be self contained enough to show you tried and what is not working. You will get rapid responses once you figure out the basic question needs

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl updated! :D

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#editable_table > tbody > tr[class*='danger'] > td:eq(3) > span").remove();
```

example:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#editable_table > tbody > tr[class*='danger'] > td:eq(3) > span").remove();
}, 5 * 1000);
```

```html
<table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody><tr id="31" class="danger">
        <td></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode">
            <span class="tabledit-span" style="display: inline;">123</span>
            <input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm fas fa-eye-slash" type="password" name="PASSWORD" value="" style="display: none;" id="password0" disabled="">
        </td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!